# Why the Angular HttpClient Type-checking doesn't work with Map?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-httpclient

There is server-side that sends a valid JSON (verified) represented a `Map<string,string>` (e.g., `{"a":"b","c":"d"}`). 
On the client-side we intentioned to use the HttpClient's Type-checking:

```
private dic : Map<string, string>;

private setMap()  {   
    this.httpClient.get<Map<string, string>>('/settings').subscribe(data => {
        this.dic = data;   
    });
```

Surprisingly, the return `data` isn't from type `Map<string, string>` but it's an `Object`.

I know that I can bypass the problem via `.map` etc. 
My question is why is it not working as expected, and where is my mistake.

Thank you

Comment: A map isn't the same as a JSON object.

Comment: @IngoBürk can you please elaborate a little?

Comment: `{"a":"b","c":"d"}` is not a `Map<string, string>`. It's a json/javascript object. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map